# Periodic Microsoft Excel to Access Import (Incomplete Data)

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, import, append

Is there a way to append records from excel in to my main table allowing the user to still add additional fields in to the same table? I already have a search box that will populate the form with the record you search for. So, ideally, the user types search criteria for one (unique) field, then about half of the fields should auto-populate so the user can manually enter the remaining half and save the updated record.

This needs to be done multiple times per day, so im trying to find the easiest/most reliable way possible!

Also, data-validation is not good in the excel source (another reason we are building this database). So the imported data is not 100% consistent (all entered manually by people)!

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via VBA. It will be a little time consuming, but if you're intending this to be a long term solution (I hope not?) then you'll need to do it that way. Here is a little snippet for you to start with:

```
   'Open Excel and grab data
   Dim oExcel As Object
   Dim oBook As Object
   Dim oSheet As Object
   Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set oSheet = oExcel.Open("PathOfWorksheet").Worksheets("WorksheetNumber")

   msgbox oSheet.cells(1, 1).Value

   oExcel.Quit
```

Combine that with `CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO tblMyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (val1,val2)"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I am looking for a long-term solution so is there not a better way to do this? The point of the access database is to take an existing database (cloud-based software, manually entered with few fields about each record and very minimal validation rules) and add more data to each record while implementing strict validation rules. If access is not the right tool to use for this then I will gladly try something different altogether. I used access because we wanted the simple forms and reporting module, and probably only need to scale to the 10,000 of rows.

Comment: I think the main issue here is that I want to enforce strict data validation rules on all the fields, but I want the appended data to be able to bypass those rules the first time (entering a new record with multiple NULL fields) but make sure the rules are applied when the record is saved via the form.

Comment: Access sounds fine for your purposes. I meant that importing data from excel files is undesirable long term. If you can't avoid it then the above method is the best way to do it - it will allow you to validate data on the fly where possible. If you like you can do all of the heavy validation on the form the users will be completing the record entry. You will need to have very relaxed table definitions (allow nulls etc) which means you must be vigilant with your VBA validation. It won't be a 30 minute job, but you will get there!

Comment: That makes sense! What I will do is validate all the fields in the main table that dont come from excel using VBA, and validate all the other fields in the table properties. That wont be too bad!